# Adding unknown amount of pages to asp.net C# view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I am trying to add pagination to an ASP.net web app using MVC. Currently I have a controller that simply returns a list of objects from the database to the view.

```
 public ActionResult List()
    { 
        return View(db.Classes.ToList());
    }
```

and in my view I am accessing the data to print out all items like,

```
 @foreach (var i in Model)
{
    <div class="block">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Class", new { ClassID = (i.ClassID) })">
            <div class="classItem">
                <div class="title">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Name => i.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Description => i.Description)
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
}
```

I get a nice list of my data, but was wondering how I might add the ability for the data to be displayed in pages if the amount of items was over a certain amount?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList

Comment: Is there a way to do it without including any external packages?

Comment: You need to write a lot of code to do that. Basically whatever the library does, you have to do it yourself

Comment: There are many examples of pagination online. What have you tried and what specific issue have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .Skip(N) and .Take(N)

```
private int pageLength = 10;

    public ActionResult List(int? page)
        { 
            var currentPage = page ?? 0;
            return View(db.Classes
                          .Skip(currentPage * pageLength)
                          .Take(pageLength)
                          .ToList());
        }
```

That is an example, you should consider nullRef and out of bounds exceptions